# Как правильно объеденить две таблицы в запросе?

Tags: php, mysql

Есть две таблицы MySql

1. master_table со структурой
   id(int), master(varchar), services(varchar)

1, 'Маша Петрова', '1,2'

2. services_table  со структурой

id(int), usluga(varchar)
1, 'Одна услуга'
2, 'Вторая услуга'
нужно на выходе получить массив такого типа

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [master_id] => 1
            [services_id] => 1,2
            [master] => Маша Петрова
            [services] => Одна услуга,Вторая услуга
        )
    [1] => Array(...)
)
```

Правильным ли будет такой запрос, или можно написать другим способом?

```
SELECT m.id AS master_id, m.services, m.master, s.id, s.usluga AS usluga
FROM master_table m
LEFT JOIN services_table s ON s.id > 0
HAVING FIND_IN_SET(s.id, m.services) > 0
```

Пробовал вот так (код просто как пример, на значения там не обращайте внимания)

```
SELECT u.user_id, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT c.category_name) AS category_names, u.category_id, c.category_id
FROM user u
INNER JOIN category c ON c.category_id > 0 
WHERE u.user_id = $user_id 
GROUP BY u.user_id 
HAVING FIND_IN_SET(c.category_id, u.category_id) > 0
```

но получаю ошибки
Суть не в том, что возвращает такой запрос, а в том верен такой запрос или нет, а если нет - то буду очень благодарен за листинг правильного запроса))
Спасибо!

Comment: А я пробовал с ними, скорее всего конечно неправильно что-то делал, получал в итоге ошибки. Вам не сложно будет привести правильный код? Я добавил неправильный код в ответ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sql
SELECT u.id master_id, 
       GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT c.usluga) AS services, 
       u.master, 
       u.services services_id
FROM master_table u
INNER JOIN services_table c ON FIND_IN_SET(c.id, u.services)
WHERE u.id = $user_id 
GROUP BY 1, 3, 4
```

Использованы имена таблиц и полей из описания структуры и требуемого результата. Имена из текстов запросов проигнорированы как не соответствующие предыдущей информации.

Comment: Akina спасибо! То что нужно! Не могли бы пояснить, что делает вот это GROUP BY 1, 3, 4 ? Если что-либо изменить в запросе, эти параметры надо будет менять? Это я так, на всякий случай. Еще раз вам огромное спасибо!

Comment: @Volloff В GROUP BY могут указываться не только поля/выражения, но и номера. `GROUP BY 1, 3, 4` означает "группировать по 1,3 и 4 полю выходного набора", т.е. это то же, что `GROUP BY master_id, master, services_id` или там `GROUP BY u.id, u.master, u.services`. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html - *Columns selected for output can be referred to in ORDER BY and GROUP BY clauses using column names, column aliases, or column positions. Column positions are integers and begin with 1*

Comment: Понял, спасибо!